# SSE for subset much better than full data

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

I am running k-fold cross validation on a complex neural network model.  I often can get the situation where on a particular k-fold, the SSE (sum of squared prediction errors) for the reduced data set plus the SSE for the predicted subset is < the SSE for the original full data set.

My sense is that something is wrong.  Am I correct or not?

Example:

- full data set SSE = 100
- fit to 90% of data = 75
- predicted SSE of remaining 10% = 15

Answer (score 1):

Typically learning with neural networks uses the back-propagation algorithm to minimize SSE of the errors. This will generally find a local minimum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_optimum) of SSE and is not guaranteed to find the global minimum. Depending on the initialization of parameters the algorithm may converge to a different local minimum.

In your example, when training the full model it seems that the algorithm has got stuck on a local minimum, as there is clearly another model (using a subset of available data) that has smaller SSE.

Comment: Are there alternative explanations?  I'm actually not using back-prop for this.  The problem is a complex one where the weights and biases of the neural network are only part of the problem, and it is a constrained optimization (a typical model might have say 30 weights and biases and 230 equality constraints --- one for each observation).